# Calling make from a bash script won't make

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

I'm writing a shell script which iterates over a set of variables, edits a source file line by line according to the current iteration value, then remakes, and finally calls the just compiled binary. After execution the old line is restored.

Here is a snippet:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in 0..4; do
    perl -i -pe "s/.*/{SUBS[$i]}/ if $. == ${LINE[$i]}" ${SOURCE}
    make
    ./bin/myTool
    perl -i -pe "s/.*/\/\/{SUBS[$i]}/ if $. == ${LINE[$i]}" ${SOURCE}
done
```

Basically I have about 10 mutually exclusive `#define` in a C++ source file, and I'm experimenting the effects of each. Since I'm lazy I'd like to make it an automated process, and here I stuck.

Sometimes it happens that the shell says:

```
`make: Nothing to be done for 'all'`
```

Now, I tried to `diff` the file before and after every `perl`instruction and the files do appear correct... I can't figure why this happens and how to make it behave correct.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Fixed, and the mistake was completely mine. I added the `sleep` instruction but definitely in the wrong place... just put it at the beginning of the loop (as correctly stated in the answers) and everything went fine. Thanks!

Comment: Last version of the script: instead of putting to sleep, I preferred to `touch -t 1010101010 ${SOURCE} ${OBJECT}`... Less time wasted! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably looping too quickly for make to tell each iteration apart. Either remove the make products or add a delay of 2 seconds at the beginning or end of the loop.

Comment: I've tried both ways but none is working properly.

First I put a `touch ${SOURCE}` just before `make` but nothing noticeable changed; `make clean && make` seems to be working but I don't want to believe that everything must be rebuilt each time.
I also tried to delete just the `.o` but still no news. A `sleep 3s` still won't do the job.

It just seems as if each line is launched in its own thread, hence such an asynchronous behaviour (oh, I tried to `wait` with no success).

Answer (score 1):

Make only checks if the target timestamp is younger than the source timestamp. That's the only way it can know what needs to be updated. So, if you loop iterations take less than a second then make won't know that anything has changed.

You can either clean up at the top of each iteration or add a delay as Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams has noted.